# Can't create EOS Account with eosjs library (UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning)

Tags: eosjs, node

I have already run this code few weeks back and back then it was working perfectly but now it's giving me an error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: account names can only be 12 chars long

I guess I haven't even change the code, but this error is coming, please let me know if I have made any mistake.
Also, I'm giving the name and public key of a new account through Postman and I have also printed it in console, it's coming without any mistakes.

Code:

```
const express = require('express');
const path= require('path');
const app =express();

const { Api, JsonRpc, RpcError } = require('eosjs');
const { JsSignatureProvider } = require('eosjs/dist/eosjs-jssig');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');   
const defaultPrivateKey = "creator account private key"; // bob
const signatureProvider = new JsSignatureProvider([defaultPrivateKey]);

const rpc = new JsonRpc('http://jungle2.cryptolions.io:80', { fetch });

const api = new Api({ rpc, signatureProvider, textDecoder: new TextDecoder(), textEncoder: new TextEncoder() });

//Body parser Middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));      



app.post('/', (req,res) => {
            
  var existingaccount = 'microfinanc1'
  var mynewaccount=req.body.eosname;
  var  pubkey=req.body.publickey;

  console.log('Is it working');
  console.log(pubkey);
  console.log(mynewaccount);


  (async () => {
    await api.transact({
      actions: [{
        account: 'eosio',
        name: 'newaccount',
        authorization: [{
          actor: existingaccount,
          permission: 'active',
        }],
        data: {
          creator: existingaccount,
          name: mynewaccount,
          owner: {
            threshold: 1,
            keys: [{
              key: pubkey,
              weight: 1
            }],
            accounts: [],
            waits: []
          },
          active: {
            threshold: 1,
            keys: [{
              key: pubkey,
              weight: 1
            }],
            accounts: [],
            waits: []
          },
        },
      },
      {
        account: 'eosio',
        name: 'buyrambytes',
        authorization: [{
          actor: existingaccount,
          permission: 'active',
        }],
        data: {
          payer: existingaccount,
          receiver: mynewaccount,
          bytes: 8192,
        },
      },
      {
        account: 'eosio',
        name: 'delegatebw',
        authorization: [{
          actor: existingaccount,
          permission: 'active',
        }],
        data: {
          from: existingaccount,
          receiver: mynewaccount,
          stake_net_quantity: '1.0000 EOS',
          stake_cpu_quantity: '1.0000 EOS',
          transfer: false,
        }
      }]
    }, {
      blocksBehind: 3,
      expireSeconds: 30,
    });
  })
  
  ();


  
});

const port = process.env.port || 5000;
app.listen(port ,()=> console.log(`server got started on port ${port} `));
```

Error in console:

```
guru@ubuntu:~/nodejs/express js$ node index.js
server got started on port 5000 
Is it working
EOS5nktguDXboGwb2YfXu6AW7bgZ2eCd1LnEie8ogJYgDyiHScDw6
 guru12341111
(node:12713) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: account names can only be 12 chars long
    at new RpcError (/home/guru/nodejs/express js/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-rpcerror.js:26:28)
    at JsonRpc.<anonymous> (/home/guru/nodejs/express js/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-jsonrpc.js:118:35)
    at step (/home/guru/nodejs/express js/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-jsonrpc.js:36:23)
    at Object.next (/home/guru/nodejs/express js/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-jsonrpc.js:17:53)
    at fulfilled (/home/guru/nodejs/express js/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-jsonrpc.js:8:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:86:5)
(node:12713) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:12713) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error message implies the account name you provided is not 12 characters, and it does seem like the account name that was sent to the server has a preceding whitespace character.